# Is there a way to implement an outward 3D view in an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ios, view, 3d, space

I wish to make an informative application, for iPad and iPhone, about the different celestial bodies in space, so I was thinking if there was a way to implement a kind of a 3D view  that would enable the user to zoom-in and out from a center point (Earth) towards the outer regions of the 3D space so that the information regarding the stars and galaxies they come across can be displayed accordingly?

When I was searching for a way, I was only able to find ways to do the opposite, i.e., to zoom-in or out towards an object, like a vase, and therefore provide a 360 degree 3D view of that object.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This would be a classical area for OpenGL - learn about using it and you will get all the tools for covering your task.